# How to rename multiply attributes name in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

this is my main xml:
`<tag tag_id="1452" type="0" date="2016-04-25" attr="20" flag="0" ntef="28" norfe="1934" kol="0" op="0" mid="" max="1" min"0.00" ... />`
Second one (file.xml):

```
<tt>
    <tag>
        <name2>value</name2>
        <name1>ntef</name1>
    </tag>
    ...
</tt>
```

I want to rename attributes in main xml if they exist in second xml in tag "name1". New name get from name2.
My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" encoding="windows-1251"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Title ', local-name(),'&#xA;')"/>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="language" select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="toText" select="@*"/>

    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="." mode="language">
    <xsl:variable name="attr" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="document('file.xml')/tt/tag[name1=$attr]" />

        <xsl:variable name="name"  select="$data/name2)" />
        <xsl:attribute name="{$name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="toText">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'=', ., '&#xA;'" />   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code is executed without any errors, but in output there is no any renamed attributes. I cannot specify attribute name because its too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key and check whether there is a reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="transformation-doc" select="doc('tt.xml')"/>

  <xsl:key name="att-ref" match="tt/tag/name2" use="../name1"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="tag/@*[key('att-ref', name(), $transformation-doc)]">
      <xsl:attribute name="{key('att-ref', name(), $transformation-doc)}" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMC6

Comment: thanks, it is useful for me. But when I paste it in me example where there are other templates, I continue work with old xml without any changes. Do you know why?

Comment: @Wiggi, consider to ask that in a new, separate question where you exactly show the current code you have and explain what the templates you use are supposed to do. In general, to make use of template based transformations where you delegate each micro-transformation (like the attribute name change) to a template of its own, the only issue you have to pay attention to is the make sure you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>` further up the hierarchy. But in XSLT 3 with the use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` you declare that and would only add templates as needed.